# Access successCallback in AngularJs $http Method

Tags: angularjs, scope

I want to access to response `successCallback(response)`

```
var list_of_user = $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/users/'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.all_users = response.data;

}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
});

console.log("$scope.all_users  ", $scope.all_users)
```

is undefiend

I can access `$scope.all_users` from html, but how can I access to `$scope.all_users` in controller?

Comment: Same controller or different controller ?

Comment: same controller. But I dont know why I have always undefined

Comment: that is simply accessed using `$scope.all_users` but make sure that ajax call completes before you access that.

Comment: I have edited my question. console.log("$scope.all_queues  ", $scope.all_queues)  is undefiend

Comment: As noted by @AdnanUmer you first start the HTTP-Request and then instantly try to `console.log` the data while the request is still running.

Comment: First you set response to `$scope.all_users` and you are logging `$scope.all_queues` so that will always be undefined. Further $http is async so `console.log` is called before response is received.

Comment: @AdnanUmer so how can I store $scope.all_users ?

Comment: Didn't even see that error "^^. As a possible fix you could either do the `console.log` inside the `then` function or do something like a two-way-binding on `$scope.all_users`, since the binding will be automatically updated on data change. If you don't want your logic inside `then` you could also `$watch` your `$scope.all_users` variable

Comment: @AdnanUmer is correct.  Move your console.log of $scope.all_users to the successCallback function.  You're referencing the $scope.all_users before it's been set by the response.

Comment: under successCallback, every thins in ok. But I have to access $scope.all_users after request

Comment: @TheNone please elaborate what you mean from storing ? Do you wanna cache that within localStorage or within variable ?

Comment: @AdnanUmer within variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http` is async and `console.log` is executed before actually request is completed.

As you defined in comment that you want to compare two responses you can do that by simply putting a flag that will wait for both requests to finish.

```
var done = 0;
var onRequestFinishes = function() {
    done += 1;
    if (done < 2) {
        return; // one of both request is not completed yet
    }

    // compare $scope.response1 with $scope.response2 here
}
```

and send first request and save response to `$scope.response1` and invoke `onRequestFinishes` after that.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/users/'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.response1 = response.data;
    onRequestFinishes();
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Similarly send second request

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/users/'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.response2 = response.data;
    onRequestFinishes();
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For request handling you can create individual promise chains and use `$q.all()` to execute code when all promises are resolved.

```
var request1 = $http.get('/users/').then(function(response)
{
    console.log('Users: ', response.data);
    return response.data;
}

var request2 = $http.get('/others/').then(function(response)
{
    console.log('Others: ', response.data);
    return response.data;
}

$q.all([request1, request2]).then(function(users, others)
{
    console.log('Both promises are resolved.');
    //Handle data as needed
    console.log(users);
    console.log(others);
}
```